# OpenCV: randn() generator like in matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am looking for the best solution to generate (in OpenCV) a matrix(2xN) of random numbers with mean 0 and variance 1,  like the function *randn()* in Matlab.

There is a `randn()` function in the OpenCV libraries, but I don't know how to pass arguments to this function to generate numbers with mean 0 and variance 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OpenCV has a [randn()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20randn%28InputOutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20mean,%20InputArray%20stddev%29) function and also a [RNG](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#rng) class. Below is the Matlab code you might want to replace, and the equivalent OpenCV code.

**Matlab:**

```
matrix2xN = randn(2,N)
```

**OpenCV:**

```
cv::Mat mean = cv::Mat::zeros(1,1,CV_64FC1);
cv::Mat sigma= cv::Mat::ones(1,1,CV_64FC1);
cv::RNG rng(optional_seed);
cv::Mat matrix2xN(2,N,CV_64FC1);
rng.fill(matrix2xN, cv::RNG::NORMAL, mean, sigma);
```

or

```
cv::Mat mean = cv::Mat::zeros(1,1,CV_64FC1);
cv::Mat sigma= cv::Mat::ones(1,1,CV_64FC1);
cv::randn(matrix2xN,  mean, sigma);
```

Internally, OpenCV implements `randn()` using `RNG`. The disadvantage if using `randn()` is that you lose control over the seed.

If `matrix2xN` above had more than one channel then a different mean/sigma is used for each channel. In which case you would need to inrease the number of rows (or cols) in mean and sigma to match the number of channels in matrix2xN.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. +1.  As a sidenote, it seems wasteful in the API design to have to specify a `cv::Mat` of only one element in order to specify the mean or standard deviation.... wouldn't a scalar, or `cv::Scalar` be more suitable instead? Weird.