# Generate random numbers matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, matrix, random

I want to know how can I generate a matrix of random numbers of any given size, for example `2x4`. Matrix should consists of signed whole number in range, for example `[-500, +500]`.

I have read the documentation of [RNG](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#rng), but I am not sure on how I should use this. 
I referred too this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037187/opencv-randn-generator-like-in-matlab) but this did not provide me the solution I am looking for.

I know this might be a silly question, but any help on it would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want values to be *uniformly* distributed, you can use [cv::randu](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#randu)

```
Mat1d mat(2, 4); // Or: Mat mat(2, 4, CV_64FC1);
double low = -500.0;
double high = +500.0;
randu(mat, Scalar(low), Scalar(high));
```

Note that the upper bound is exclusive, so this example represents data in range `[-500, +500)`.

---

If you want values to be *normally* distributed, you can use [cv::randn](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#randn)

```
Mat1d mat(2, 4); // Or: Mat mat(2, 4, CV_64FC1);
double mean = 0.0;
double stddev = 500.0 / 3.0; // 99.7% of values will be inside [-500, +500] interval
randn(mat, Scalar(mean), Scalar(stddev));
```

---

This works for matrices up to 4 channels, e.g.:

```
Mat3b random_image(100,100);
randu(random_image, Scalar(0,0,0), Scalar(256,256,256));
```

Comment: Thank you @Miki . But what is Mat1d?

Comment: it's a `typedef` for  `Mat_<double>`. It's just easier to use than a `Mat` of type `CV_64FC1`. The above code works for `Mat` as well: `Mat mat(2,4,CV_64FC1);`

Comment: Thank you @Miki. I willl try it.

Comment: All solutions works fine @Miki. Thank you. But I have 1 question.why do I get output as double even if I change low and high to int? Is it possible I get it as int?

Comment: Just change the type of the matrix. Use "Mat1i"