# Find the index and value of column maximum in openCV matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

This is the original MATLAB implementation

```
function[m, p] = max2(im)

[m1, k1] = max(im);
[m, k2] = max(m1);

x = k2;
y = k1(k2);

p = [y, x];
```

It is being used inside this functionality

```
for r = 2.^linspace(log2(minR),log2(maxR),numSteps);
    itestSeek = imresize(itestBase,minR/r);    
    icorr = normxcorr2(cc,itestSeek);
    [m,p] = max2(icorr); //here
    if (m>bestm)
        bestp = p*r;
        bests = ccSize*r;
        bestm = m;        
    end;
end;
```

Here is my OpenCV 3.0.0/ c++ implementation

```
void Utilities::Max2(cv::Mat input_image, double& m, std::vector<int>& p)
{
    std::vector<double> m1(input_image.cols); // the local maximum for each column
    std::vector<int> k1(input_image.cols); // the index of the local maximum
    for (int c = 0; c < input_image.cols; ++c)
    {
        float temp_max = input_image.at<float>(0, c);
        int temp_index = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < input_image.rows; ++r)
        {
            if (temp_max < input_image.at<float>(r, c))
            {
                temp_max = input_image.at<float>(r, c);
                temp_index = r;
            }
        }
        m1[c] = temp_max;
        k1[c] = temp_index;
    }
    auto iter = std::max_element(m1.begin(), m1.end()); //max of all the local maximum;
    m = *iter;
    int k2 = std::distance(m1.begin(), iter);

    double y = k1[k2];
    p.push_back(y);
    p.push_back(k2);
}
```

c++ usage of the function

```
std::vector<double> best_p;
std::vector<double> best_s;
for (double i = 0; i < linspace_vector.size(); i++)
{
    cv::Mat i_test_seek;
    cv::Mat i_corr;
    double r = linspace_vector[i];
    double resize_factor = min_r / r; // minR/r in matlab
    cv::resize(i_test_base, i_test_seek, cv::Size(), resize_factor, resize_factor, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    cv::matchTemplate(i_test_seek, cc_template, i_corr, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);

    cv::imshow("i_corr", i_corr);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    double m;
    std::vector<int> p;

    Utilities::Max2(i_corr, m, p);
    if (m>  best_m)
    {
        best_p.clear();
        best_s.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
        {
            best_p.push_back(p[i] * r);
        }
        best_s.push_back(cc_size_height * r);
        best_s.push_back(cc_size_width * r);
        best_m = m;
    }
}
```

Can you suggest a more efficient way of doing this?
I find the local maximum for each column and the index of that value.

Later I find the global maximum of all of the indices.

Comment: changed the title, because "find index of column" was a bit confusing imho

Comment: assuming this is working code, your question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the image is column wise in memory, switching the inner and outerloop may improve performance, because there are less cache misses. Although the compiler might do that for you.

Comment: @OutOfBound the cv::Mat is row wise and I need to go over the image column wise(like matlab)

Comment: Finding the global maximum should be independet of how you traverse the image. Why do you have to stick to the way matlab is doing it?

Comment: @OutOfBound I add my code, where I use this function both for matlab and both for c++

Comment: Do you need to build a list or are you only interested in the max of max? 'cv::reduce' is probably your friend.

Comment: Why not `minMaxLoc`?

Comment: @Miki I will try it. i just tried to understand what this code is doing, maybe to learn something from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following and benchmark, if the performance increases:

```
#include <limits>


void Utilities::Max2(cv::Mat input_image, double& m, std::vector<int>& p)
{
    m = std::numeric_limits<double>::min;
    std::pair<int, int> temp_index = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < input_image.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < input_image.cols; ++c)
        {
            if (m < input_image.at<float>(r, c))
            {
                m = input_image.at<float>(r, c);
                temp_index = std::make_pair(c, r);
            }
        }
    }

    p[0] = temp_index.second;
    p[1] = temp_index.first;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a way to get the input as a vector and you can get the number col columns, for example using:

```
int cols = input_image.rows;
std::vector<double> v;
v.assign(input_image.datastart, input_image.dataend);
```

Then you can compute in just one go:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator iter = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
double m = *iter;
int k = std::distance(v.begin(), iter);
int y = (int)k / cols;
int x = k % cols;
```

However, I am not sure if getting the data as a vector is an option nor the performance of convert it into a vector. Maybe you can run and see how it compares to your implementation.

Comment: You can directly use `Mat` iterators. They also handle correctly non-continuous matrices

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of code is essentially finding the max value and its indices (both x and y) in an image to my understanding.

```
function[m, p] = max2(im)
    [m1, k1] = max(im); %find the max value in each col
    [m, k2] = max(m1);  %find the max value among maxes

    x = k2;             %find the "row" of the max value
    y = k1(k2);         %and its "col"
    p = [y, x];
```

This can be done using some iterations but iteration is almost always significantly slower than vector operations or Opencv functions.

So, if my understanding is correct, this operation can simply be done by

```
double minVal, maxVal;
Point minLoc, maxLoc;
minMaxLoc(im, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
```

`maxLoc.y` will give the row, and `maxLoc.x` will give col.

**update**: Your Matlab code can also be simplified (which potentially will speed up too)

```
[mx, ind] = max(im(:));
p = [rem(ind,size(im,1)) ceil(ind/size(im,1))];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following:

```
// creating a random matrix with 2 rows and 4 columns
Mat1d mat(2, 4); 
double low = -7000.0;  // minimum value for generating random numbers
double high = +7000.0; // maximum value for generating random numbers
randu(mat, Scalar(low), Scalar(high)); // generating random number matrix

double max_element = *std::max_element(mat.begin(),mat.end()); // get the max element in the matrix
int max_element_index = std::max_element(mat.begin(),mat.end()) - mat.begin(); // get the max_element_index from the matrix`
```

The max element index is a row major order value starting from 0 until number of items in the matrix, in this case 7,

```
cout << mat << endl;
cout << max_element << endl;
cout << max_element_index << endl;
```

[Referred [Generate random numbers matrix in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526127/generate-random-numbers-matrix-in-opencv) for the code above]